# How to get SharePoint group ID from group Name or Title

Tags: spgroup

How can I get MemberGroupId (Here 135) of particular SPGroup programmatically (Sharepoint 2010, C#) if I have SPGroup Name/Title?
I can get a group by ID as given below.

```
SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups.GetByID(135);
```

I want to get same by title or SPgroup Name. Is there any alternative method or any how if I can get ID from Group name as I can't hard code group ID as in production ID will not remain same for the same group.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try it as :

```
SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups["groupName"];
var groupID = group.ID;
```

or

```
SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups.GetByName("groupName");
var groupID = group.ID;
```

Reference - [SPGroupCollection.GetByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroupcollection.getbyname.aspx) method

Answer (score 2):

I am proposing to do something like this :

```
public SPGroup SearchGroupByName(string groupName)
 {
   SPGroup groupObject = null;
   foreach(SPGroup singleGroup in this.SPWebLocation.Groups)
   {
    if(groupName == singleGroup.Name)
    {
      groupObject = singleGroup;
    }
   }
   return groupObject;
 }
```

This method returns you the group by name.

after that you can retrieve from the group resultat the Id as a propriety.

Hope that will help you.
Best regards.